# Android sdk version on gradle and manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I started using Android Studio a few weeks ago and there's a question I have, in the build.gradle file we can set the minSdkVersion as we can in the manifest, but does one override the other? if we put different values on gradle and on the manifest what is the consequence?

Comment: voted to keep open - this question is exactly about the tools an Android developer uses, and the user's concern is quite valid I believe. In order to test this premise requires uploading various apps to google play store and trying to download them on devices. This can be time consuming, and so this question is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manifest files in your projects are overridden by the gradle when you build your projects.