# User permissions

Tags: android, security, android-manifest

I am new to android, I want to know whether `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` have default permissions ???

This is my manifest.xml file

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.sample.test" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

But it still show `<user-permission>` as

**Uses Permissions:**

1. android.permission.INTERNET
2. android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
3. android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

**Defines Permissions:**

1. None

Is there any other way to define such permissions

I am using `drozer` to check vulnerability in my app
Thanks.

Comment: no , you have to add all permission what you need for your app.

Comment: ok... but it still show me `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps didn't need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the past to access external storage. But that will change in the near future (see 'Caution' section in the referenced guide). So, previously apps were able to write to external storage by default. Also, `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` includes `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` so you don't need to obtain both.

Here's the relevant user guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#GetWritePermission

So, for devices with API level 23 and later add the respective permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: So, where should I come to know which API level I am using...??

Comment: You specifiy it when you create your project. It is defined in your manifest file.

Comment: But I have not specify any of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.....!

Comment: I have give my `menifest.xml` file

Comment: You will need to specify it if you run your app on devices with API 23 and later.

Comment: Is it coding level or configuration level

Comment: My question is, I have not define any permission in manifest.xml and still showing

Comment: Yes, it works because you are probably running on API level <= 22. I suggest you try to run your app on an emulator with API level 23.

Comment: check my manifest.xml   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
`

Comment: The definition in the gradle file overrides the ones in the manifest file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448677/android-sdk-version-on-gradle-and-manifest

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: [A basic Android application has **no** permissions associated with it by default](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html). See the section labeled *Using Permissions*.

Comment: I read the same......! I have given only one permission and it show me two extra..... How is it possible....? Is there any another way to define permissions....